# What is the point of checking same condition twice in if statement and assert statement?

Tags: python, if-statement, assert

Is there any reason checking the same condition twice in if statement and assert statement?

```
    if args.output:
        if os.path.isdir(args.output):
            assert os.path.isdir(args.output), args.output
```

It's from demo.py file from Facebook's Detectron2 Github source code. If you want to see where this code came from, more codes are below here:

```
if args.input:
    if len(args.input) == 1:
        args.input = glob.glob(os.path.expanduser(args.input[0]))
        assert args.input, "The input path(s) was not found"
    for path in tqdm.tqdm(args.input, disable=not args.output):
        # use PIL, to be consistent with evaluation
        img = read_image(path, format="BGR")
        start_time = time.time()
        predictions, visualized_output = demo.run_on_image(img)
        logger.info(
            "{}: detected {} instances in {:.2f}s".format(
                path, len(predictions["instances"]), time.time() - start_time
            )
        )

        if args.output:
            if os.path.isdir(args.output):
                assert os.path.isdir(args.output), args.output
                out_filename = os.path.join(args.output, os.path.basename(path))
            else:
                assert len(args.input) == 1, "Please specify a directory with args.output"
                out_filename = args.output
            visualized_output.save(out_filename)
        else:
            cv2.namedWindow(WINDOW_NAME, cv2.WINDOW_NORMAL)
            cv2.imshow(WINDOW_NAME, visualized_output.get_image()[:, :, ::-1])
            if cv2.waitKey(0) == 27:
                break  # esc to quit
```

Comment: There's no good reason to do that.

Comment: @HeapOverflow Thanks. Here is the link - https://github.com/facebookresearch/detectron2/blob/5db4ea37627cf578b7763cb9dc2e110f96f4dbf6/demo/demo.py#L96

Comment: Ok, had a look. I thought maybe this evolved from originally different expressions, but at least as far as the history there shows, they've been like that since the initial commit.

Comment: Sometimes code that was previously useful becomes redundant as the rest of the surrounding code evolves.  Both of these lines may have been useful independently at some point

Comment: @HymnsForDisco Thanks for commenting. So, it's just a tiny mistake? Or, the authors intentionally left them so that those lines can be used again in the future? I'm asking a general situation.